# Bootstrap datepicker setDatesDisabled not working on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to setDatesDisabled on button click for bootstrap datepicker, however it's not working.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="date-range">
    <div class="range-start"></div>
    <div class="range-end"></div>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="btn btn-warning">Disable Dates</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $('#date-range').datepicker({
    inputs: $('.range-start, .range-end'),
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    datesDisabled: ['2016-04-21', '2016-04-20', '2016-04-13']
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('#date-range').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['2016-04-29', '2016-04-30']);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kaygee79/953zk742/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `inputs` specified while initializing the datepicker.

```
$(function() {
  $('#date-range').datepicker({
    inputs: $('.range-start, .range-end'),
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    datesDisabled: ['2016-04-21', '2016-04-20', '2016-04-13']
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('.range-start').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['2016-04-29', '2016-04-30']);
    $('.range-end').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ['2016-04-29', '2016-04-30']);
  });
});
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/f50ga49j/